# Intercepting Back Button in Xamarin Forms WPF

Tags: wpf, forms, xamarin, navigation, back

I tried to intercept the back navigation button by subscribing to the Navigating event in the WPF project of a Xamarin Forms solution:

`System.Windows.Application.Current.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(OnNavigating);`

But OnNavigating is never called.

Is this the correct way to do it or is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

My experience is with Xamarin.Forms on iOS/Android, but here goes:

ContentPage has an OnBackButtonPressed() event.  Here is how we use it:

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (GrdDisplayName.IsVisible)         //If grid is visible then hide it but don't exit
        {
            GrdDisplayName.IsVisible = false;
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();     //Allow exit
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But unfortunately this event is not fired in UWP and WPF.

Comment: Events are class dependent.  It would be helpful to know what object you are navigating back on.  Is it a ContentPage or....?

Comment: Yes, I am navigating back on ContentPages.

BTW, I just have noticed, that OnBackButtonPressed is also called in UWP, but not in WPF.

Comment: Per the Xamarin site, it is built for iOS, Android, and UWP.  I mistakenly thought you were talking about UWP.  If you are using WFP, I have no idea how Xamarin.Forms works or is supported.